# Jinja2 html representation in python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, jinja2

I am writing a flask powered blog and I want to present my comments saved in XML format to the browser, so I opened the XML file and I read from it.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

def blue():
with open('blogcomment.xml') as file:
    doc = parse(file)

return '\n'.join("""
        <div class="card">
            <span></span>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="date">%s</p>
                <h3></h3>
                <p class="desc">%s</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        """%(item.findtext('date'), item.findtext('body')) for item in doc.iterfind('entries/entry'))
```

Then I called blue

```
@sqldb.route('/dbresult')
def dbresult():
   f = blue()
   return f
```

**#Output:**

11/14/2007

in qui latine elaboraret, ad nam phaedrum mediocrem cotidieque.

11/18/2007

I got the new cube I ordered. It’s a real pearl.

Which is what I wanted but I want it to be in a particular section of my blog, so I created

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
{{f}}


</body>

</html>
```

And changed my route to

```
@sqldb.route('/dbresult')
def dbresult():
   f = blue()
   return render_template('dbresult.html', f=f)
```

when I ran the code It Outputted

```
<div class="card"> <span></span> <div class="content"> <p class="date">11/14/2007</p> <h3></h3> <p 
class="desc">in qui latine elaboraret, ad nam phaedrum mediocrem cotidieque.</p> </div> </div> <div 
class="card"> <span></span> <div class="content"> <p class="date">11/18/2007</p> <h3></h3> <p 
class="desc">Got the new cube I ordered. It’s a real pearl.</p> </div> </div>
```

on the browser as the browser did not interpret the HTML, is it from Jinja2 or what did I do wrong I need help.

blogcomment.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <blog>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <date>11/14/2007</date>
            <name>Jeff</name>
            <body>in qui latine elaboraret, ad nam phaedrum mediocrem cotidieque.</body>
        </entry>

        <entry>
            <date>11/18/2007</date>
            <name>Petter</name>
            <body>Got the new cube I ordered. It&#x2019;s a real pearl.</body>
        </entry>

    </entries>
</blog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask's [default configuration](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#jinja-setup) includes autoescaping for `.html` templates. Therefore when you put `{{ f }}` into the template the `f` variable is treated as an unsafe variable and any 'dangerous' character (e.g. `<` or `>`) will be escaped (converted to a HTML entity).

To prevent this behavior you can use the [safe template filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#safe), which marks the variable as safe so it will not be escaped:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
{{ f | safe }}
</body>

</html>
```

Make sure that `f` does not contain any malicious code.

A better approach would be that in your `blue` method you just prepare the data to render (e.g. make a list of dicts from the data) and then you render the comments in a template file using the built in [`for`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) control statement.